# Python Module Issue: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, pygame

I've been attempting to develop a text adventure type game in Python (and PyGame), and thus needed a module to repeatedly blit text to the screen. After searching through a few, I downloaded KTextSurfaceWriter and installed it. Then I tried to follow the demo in the text provided here (http://www.pygame.org/project-KTextSurfaceWriter-1001-.html)

My code:

```
from ktextsurfacewriter import KTextSurfaceWriter

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame.font
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480), 0, 32)

surface = pygame.surface ( (400, 400), flags = SRCALPHA, depth = 32)
surface.fill( (255,255,255,255) )

def blitSurface():
    screen.blit(surface, (50,50) )
    pygame.display.update()

blitSurface()

def waitForUserAction():
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                import sys
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                return

waitForUserAction()
```

However, this throws back the module error at line 9. I'm fairly new to Python and most of the solutions I saw for this issue involved using the 'from [module] import' code that I already have at the beginning.

Comment: Were you thinking of capital Surface? Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code and soure code.

```
surface = pygame.surface ( (400, 400), flags = SRCALPHA, depth = 32)
```

In your code, "surface" is lowercase, which is a python module, so python interpreter tells you the err msg.

```
surface = pygame.Surface( (400,400), flags=SRCALPHA, depth=32 )
```

In source code, "Surface" is capital, which may be a class.

Comment: I'm still not used to how case-sensitive Python can be, I guess. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `pygame.surface` module:

```
surface = pygame.surface ( (400, 400), flags = SRCALPHA, depth = 32)
```

Either use `pygame.surface.Surface()` or use `pygame.Surface()` (note the capital `S`); these are both the same class but `pygame.surface` is the module in which it is defined.